# Dynamically Handling Return Types in Code Generation with JavaPoet

Tags: java, spring, code-generation, javapoet

I'm facing an issue in my application where I need to generate code based on implementation properties provided by the user, such as methodName, className, arguments, and returnType. I'm using JavaPoet for code generation.

My problem lies with the returnType. I want the user to be able to simply write types like "String" or "int" and use them as return types for the generated methods. Additionally, I need to distinguish between Java built-in classes and custom classes when dealing with the returnType.

I've discovered that I can use ClassName from JavaPoet to handle custom classes, but I'm unsure how to handle Java built-in classes and determine whether the returnType provided by the user belongs to a built-in Java class or a custom class.

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to approach this issue effectively.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish in that way?

Comment: I'm considering that users can input custom types that are not available during code generation, which I'm handling using ClassName from JavaPoet. However, I'm facing an issue with built-in Java classes because I need to import them using their full classpath but i'm getting only the simple name of the class (exp String ....)

Comment: JavaPoet will take care of importing classes as much as is necessary for you.  You shouldn't need to do anything special.

Comment: I understand that JavaPoet handles the importing of classes.However, my challenge lies in receiving the type as a string from the user, such as "String". I am aware that I can use ClassName.get("java.lang", "String") or TypeName.String to handle common types, but it is not efficient to handle all possible user-provided types in this way. For custom types, I have considered using ClassName customType = ClassName.get("com.models", "Product") to represent the desired return type, such as a Product. If there are any other features or techniques in JavaPoet that I am unaware of, please let me know.

Comment: Why get the class name as a String, instead of as a [`Class`](https://square.github.io/javapoet/javadoc/javapoet/com/squareup/javapoet/ClassName.html#get(java.lang.Class))?  Just use `ClassName.get(String.class)` or `ClassName.get(Product.class)`.

Comment: To summarize my situation, I'm working with a BPMN modeler where users can select elements and provide implementation properties such as the method name and return type. I'm facing difficulties with the return type as I receive it as a string from the XML representation of the diagram. Requiring users to write the entire classpath for each type is not an efficient solution. I'm looking for an alternative approach to handle the return type effectively and efficiently.